# My car is shaking like wave on small bump

Tags: maintenance, car, shaking

I bought a new Maruti S-Scross zeta model 8 months back. After use of 6000 miles, I felt like my car is taking wave especially visible on the rear passenger head. When I show all of them from my car's rear-view mirror, I can see all of them are moving like a local train passenger (left to right moving head). Move head left to right 3/4 time after my car pass a single small pits of the regular road or in while taking C-turn in slow speed.

I hope this make sense to understand my issue with car behavior while observing small bump and road pits.

I want to know what is the reason behind this behavior and solution to it.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here. Do you mean the car is taking a long time to damp vibrations from a bump?

Comment: Do you suspect the suspension?   A car that new should be under a manufacturer's warranty too

Comment: Is the rocking pretty much left to right sway.  Or is if bouncing and floating up and down and front to back also.

Comment: @spicetraders, its shaking left to right when quick turn completed and car comes up straight on the road. The reaction was same like water move inside the bottle when you try to pick or move.

Comment: @Criggie, Yes I am afraid it may be related to a suspension however Maruti engineer has refused my doubt on that.

Comment: @Rory, Yes almost lite that. I mean to say when my car pass over from small pit or road bumps car's body from back/rear side will shake 3/4 times left to right side same like snake waves.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your struts are shot.

If you're talking about a shake/vibration at high speeds it more than likely is wheel balance.  But if your talking about rocking side to side it would be your struts.  If it is your struts I would take it back to the dealer based on the age of the vehicle.

Comment: car is 8 months old with 6k miles, struts last much longer.

Comment: Yes they do but sometimes defects happen.

Comment: Agree. I'm getting a weeping shock absorber replaced under warranty for a car that's just two years old and done 15k miles. Defects happen.

Answer (score 1):

Get your car to another garage, avoiding the previous garage, and ask for wheel "alignment" or "tracking", mentioning your issue.. For some reason your wheels seems to be changed/changing the angle, and do it as soon as you can. Might be any bolt loose.. It will cost a very little money. After that, if something was wrong, let your car dealer know it with the receipt..

Comment: Thank you so much, Arturs. I will go with your suggestion and let you know dealer response on this.

Comment: I prefer to repair my car by myself, but every time I change any part of chassis, I visit a garage just to align my wheels correctly with lasers, so my car goes straight when I want it to go straight, ignoring side winds and pot holes, and saves money on tires and fuel.